# ffmpeg hangs in avcodec_encode_video2

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg

I encode the video stream using ffmeg. Shell QT Creator. OC Windows 7. The compiler MinGW. H264 codec.

There is a function, which I give to the input frame, and I must return an encoded byte array. Within this function it hangs when calling avcodec_encode_video2, but not on the first call, and at random.
That is, an arbitrary coding frame hangs (100 to 10000).

```
QByteArray VideoEncoder::createFrameVideoFromImage(QImage picture)
{
    AVFrame* frame_source = av_frame_alloc();        
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)frame_source, picture.bits(), AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, this->width_frame, this->height_frame);

    AVFrame* frame_dst = av_frame_alloc();

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)frame_dst, (uint8_t*)this->inbuffer, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, this->width_frame, this->height_frame);

    sws_scale(this->convert_rgb_yuv, frame_source->data, frame_source->linesize,
        0, this->ctx_codec_in->height, frame_dst->data, frame_dst->linesize);

    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);
    packet.data = NULL;
    packet.size = 0;
    packet.pts = packet.dts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;

    int nOutputSize = 0;
    if (avcodec_encode_video2(this->ctx_codec_in, &packet, frame_dst, &nOutputSize) < 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "VideoEncoder error";
    }
    this->traffic += packet.size;

    QByteArray data_frame = QByteArray((char*)packet.data, packet.size);

    av_frame_free(&frame_source);
    av_frame_free(&frame_dst);
    av_free_packet(&packet);

    return data_frame;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to attach to the process, and see where it hangs

Comment: Implementation of this function within the library, in the file ".lib". The debugger can not get there. Or this may be?

Comment: If the library is not stripped, or if you provide debug symbol, sure debugger can go deep into the library.